# token recognition error at: 'Â°' for degree symbol in ANTLR4.8 C++ target

Tags: c++, unicode, antlr, antlr4

I'm getting

```
token recognition error at: 'Â°'
```

for degree symbol and I can't figure out what to do about it.

In the lexer I have defined

Degree : '\uC2B0' | '\u00F8';

The .g4 files for lexer and parser are stored in UTF-8. The input file is stored in UTF-8 as well. When I look at the input file in a hex editor the degree sign is encoded as c2 b0.

Code to read in the input file and parse

```
std::ifstream is(inputFile);

antlr4::ANTLRInputStream antlrIs(is);
TagsLexer lexer(&antlrIs);
antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
TagsParser parser(&tokens);
TagsParser::TagsContext* tagsContext = parser.tags();
```

Comment: `°` Degree sign is `\u00B0` (encoded as `\xC2\xB0` in utf-8, which _appears_ as `Â°` if interpreted in _latin1_)  `\uC2B0` is `슰` _Hangul Syllable Sios Eu Rieulsios_.

Comment: @JosefZ This put me on the right track, solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Including your full lexer grammar may be necessary here.

The recognition error begins at the \uC382 character before the \uC2B0.   From that error, I'd assume there is no lexer rule that takes a \uC382 character and can be followed by an \uC2B0.

You might try adding the following lexer rule as the very last lexer rule.:

```
BAD_CHAR: . ;
```

You want to make sure it's the VERY last rule.  It'll only match a single character, but it will match ANY single character, so it's important that ANTLR sees any other single-character lexer rules first.

Lexer rules give first priority to the longest string of input characters that match a rule, and if more than one rule matches the same number of character, it uses the first rule in your grammar.

This should tokenize the \uC382 character as a `BAD_CHAR` token, and then recognize the \uC2B0 character as a `Degree` token.  ANTLR error recovery may be able to flag and ignore the `BAD_CHAR` as an unrecognized character and move on with the parsing matching the `Degree` token.

Of course, this all assumes that \uC382 is an invalid character for you.  If it's valid then you need a rule that recognizes it.

Comment: There is no \uC382 character in the input, the character in the error message is invented by ANTLR. The last character before \uC2B0 in the input is a space 0x20.

Comment: I’ve never seen ANTLR “invent” a character in input.  If there is no \uC382 in your actual input, then I’d start looking at how your code is handling file encoding.  For anyone to assist you, it may help to see: - the code you use to open the file, - a sample of your input, - your lexer rules (all of them), - a dump of the TokenStream

Answer (score 0):

A simple case of mixing up the actual unicode symbol \u00B0 with it's encoding in UTF-8 C2 B0.